# Generative sequences in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, generative

I'm using the following code as a way to generate a sequence of length `num_steps` given `starting_point` and `starting_state` using an instance of a `RNNCell`, for example `cell=GRUCell(number_of_neurons)`.

```
outputs = [starting_point]
state = starting_state
for time_step in range(num_steps):
    if time_step > 0: tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
    (cell_output, state) = cell(outputs[time_step], state)
    outputs.append(cell_output)
```

But this is slow and cumbersome for my use case, where `num_steps = 1000`. Even instantiating the graph takes forever.

Does this functionality exist somewhere in Tensroflow, and I just missed it?

Note that what I'm looking for is similar to, but distinct from, the behavior of `tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn`. The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/static_rnn) summarizes the behavior of this function as simply applying the RNN to each time step in a sequence:

```
state = cell.zero_state(...)
  outputs = []
  for input_ in inputs:
    output, state = cell(input_, state)
    outputs.append(output)
  return (outputs, state)
```

But in my case, I want to feed the output from one step as the input to the next step.

Answer (score 2):

In the tensorflow nightly builds, see tf.contrin.seq2seq for the dynamic decoder objects. You can use the scheduled sampling helpers to do what you want. Alternatively use tf.nn.dynamic_rnn and feed all zeros as inputs.  The lstm h state is also the lstm output so you get essentially the same behavior you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer (+1). I noticed these additions in r1.1, but their usage is entirely opaque. For example, what is a decoder object? What is a helper object? Why do I need either? What do they do? Right now I've kludged the behavior I want using `legacyseq2seq.rnn_decode` by providing `loop_fn=lambda prev, i: prev` but it's still slow.

Comment: We're working on a tutorial. For now, see the unit tests for example usage.

Comment: The nighties have slightly changed the API so I suggest using those.